# How can I export trace.axd to a file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, trace

This probably has an easy answer, but I haven't been able to find one yet.  I was wondering if there was a simple solution to exporting the page-level trace results of trace.axd to a log file of some sort.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <trace> element has a **writeToDiagnosticsTrace** option, which enables you to capture trace events with a trace listener.

We have done this, but with poor results. Because of incomplete trace support in ASP.NET, we couldn't get anything but the trace event messages into the file - no timestamps, no elapsed time - nothing really useful.

Comment: Woot! It works.  Thanks man.
I used the XmlWriterTraceListener and it gave me all of the information. It looks like we might be able to use this.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here it might take you some way to what you want:

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020910.htm

Comment: That's a good article, however, it doesn't explain how to take trace.adx and store all of its information in a trace log, unless I missed something.  Thanks though.